# How to create a sensible entity structure with/without inheritance using Symfony 6/Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to write a Symfony 6.2 application using Doctrine 2.14 for ORM. It's about managing bank account entries, different kinds of costs classes and connected information.
Think of entities:

- "Entry" E for each bank account entry
- "Person" P for different persons
- "Company" C for different companies
- "Property" Y for different real estate properties
  Each item E of the type "entry" should belong to exactly one of the three costs classes. This means E has either a P or a C or a Y which is assigned to it. The cost classes are quite different in their inner structure.

In plain PHP I would have an AccountingInterface which is implemented by Person, Company and Property and an attribute "private AccountingInterface accounting" in Entry.

But how do I do this in my Doctrine model as I do not have a class inheritance here because of the great differences between Person, Company and Property?

I've read the following articles:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

But as I am quite new to this I'm not sure whether I am on the right way of thinking?

Comment: I [read this](https://romaricdrigon.github.io/2019/06/11/doctrine-inheritance) a while back and the final word "do you really need polymorphism with Doctrine" has stuck with me. You _could_ do CTI, STI or a mapped supper class, however you could also say "a Person, Company and Property aren't really related except for the fact that they _could be_ associated with an Entry". If that's the case, maybe the Entry class allows all of them, and uses setters with a union type to guard against an invalid state: https://3v4l.org/5eMoF#v8.0.28

Comment: This is by no means "the right way", just another way. It really depends on your use-case. If those things truly are related, the way that Sedan inherits Car inherits Automobile is related, than one of the official Doctrine inheritance models might be more ideal. The union type could also be replaced/supplemented with an interface if that logic works for you, too.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will study the linked postings and evaluate whether this solves my case! I'll come here back with my result.